# linux clone and pthreads

Tags: linux, pthreads, clone

What are the flags for the linux function clone to obtain the same behaviour as pthread_create?
I have tried several solutions but all gives me differents pid and not only one like with pthread_create.
I have tried CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_FS|CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES | SIGCHLD but when I run the task manager I see different tasks for every thread and not only one task like with pthread_create. I think that pthread_create use clone to create threads.

Answer (score 0):

The `CLONE_THREAD` flag causes the new thread to be in the same thread group, which means that `getpid(2)` will return the same value as in the caller.